# Remove Mac OS X and install Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, mac

Is there a way to completely remove Mac OS X from MacBook Pro and replace it with Windows 7? I’m not talking about Boot Camp, I’m talking about completely wiping disk of any files and partitioning it for Windows installation. Any BIOS, booting, compatibility problems? I know it’s rare to replace Mac OS X for Windows, but I have this one situation where this is needed so I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: One problem with installing ONLY XP.. you can't apply future firmware updates. If you don't want to use Mac OS, I suggest a BARE minimum install of Mac OS first. Then Boot Camp to partition leaving as little as 10GBs for Mac OS, and the rest for Windows. Trust me.. YOU WIIL want the ability to apply firmware updates when they are released. (I speak from experience.)

Comment: Before doing anything with the partitions that Boot Camp builds, read this: http://superuser.com/questions/735713/can-i-safely-delete-this-partition

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you do a clean install and format your disk with a MBR, it should be possible to install without either OS X or Bootcamp. Also note, that you will need the windows drivers from the OS X discs.

I haven’t tried it, so I can’t assure that it works, but see for ex. [[1](https://superuser.com/questions/64842/installing-windows-7-64-bit-on-a-mac-pro-without-bootcamp)] and [[2](http://derekhat.com/install-vista-on-a-macbook-without-bootcamp/)], resp.

Comment: I Googled a bit and found out that Windows 7 natively supports EFI so I think this solution should work, of course with OSX DVD drivers. But probably new BootCamp will bring newer drivers for Windows 7.

Comment: This is correct.  Vista didn't support EFI natively, but Win7 does.

Comment: If you are creating bootable USB make sure you use GPT (GUID Partition Table) rather than MBR (Master Boot Record) during format. Macbooks don't recognize MBR drives as bootable.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, its possible.

Insert Mac OS X Install Disc (this part should work with OS X 10.4 Tiger or OS X 10.5 Leopard discs).

Reboot.  Hold down C key during reboot
Do not start the install.  From the Utilities menu, select Disk Utility.

Select your hard drive from the list and then click the Partition tab / button.

Click the Options button and select “Master Boot Record” as the partition scheme.  Click OK.

From the Volume Scheme drop down list, select 1 Partition.  Select MS-DOS (FAT) for the format (not that this matters since you will reformat it using NTFS during the Vista install).

Click Apply.

Reboot.  Hold down the Alt/Option key turning reboot.

When the graphical boot menu appears, hit the eject button.  Take out the OS X Install Disc and put in your Vista with SP1 install disc.

Proceed through the Vista install.

When you come to screen titled “Where do you want to install Windows,” select Disk 0.

There will be a message saying that you cannot install to that disk because it is not formatted using NTFS.

Click the Drive Options link.  Click the Format link.  Click OK in the confirmation dialog.

Now select Disk 0 and click Next.

The Vista installation should proceed as normal.

Once Windows is installed and loaded, insert an OS X 10.5 Leopard disc and install the Windows drivers from Apple.

Thanks to "Derek Hatchard's Information Flume Ride"

Answer (score 0):

No, Macs don't use BIOS they use EFI. Because of that, you need to use OSX + Bootcamp to run Windows.

Comment: See my comment to Debilski

Comment: I wasn't aware that 7 supported EFI - in that case, this only applies to older versions of Windows.