# Remove Mac OS and install Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove Mac OS X and install Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/73965/remove-mac-os-x-and-install-windows)

I'd like to run a new 11.6" MacBook Air exclusively on Windows 7 without wasting any 'space' on the Mac OS.  Is there a SIMPLE way to install Win 7 and completely erase Mac OS?

Comment: I believe it's possible with Boot Camp. I used Google with your question and a LOT of stuff came up. You might want to read up about that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, attach a CDROM drive, boot from MacOS (hold down the C key while the device boots).  When The install routine starts, select your language and go to disk utilities at the top of the screen.

Select the partition on the left, and erase it.  Restart the computer with Win7 in the Rom drive.  Install Win7 remembering to delete the largest partition on the disk (the old HFS+ partition created by OS X), and put a new NTFS one on it.

Complete the install of Win7.  Congratulations, downgrade complete. ;)

Comment: I believe that you had a typo in there (the downgrade part). I think you meant upgrade. Good directions though! +1 :D

Comment: Riiiiiiiight :)

Comment: Thanks Everett!  If only everyone communicated as clearly as you do...  Any suggestions as to how I should partition the 160 GB hard drive?

Comment: Harrymc does have a point.  On one hand, it's not a bad idea to have a backup OS.  However, in order for this to be useful, you have to have the content of your HD readable by the OS.  This means formatting FAT32.  You won't be able to store files above 4GB.  You can't format ExFAT on an internal drive and have Win7 recognize it.  If you format NTFS (Win7 likes this) then you have to add software to OS X to make it compatible.  There is a security risk to be addressed for having a "backdoor" OS on a system too.

Comment: Ouch, this is way over my pay grade.  Bottom line, in case of trouble, can I simply boot the Mac OS from the USB device which is included in the original package from Apple?  At the risk, of course, of losing all Win 7 data, which will be backed up anyway.

Comment: Yes, you can boot from whatever Apple provides, but you may loose your data.

Comment: I do not agree that OSX needs to be able to read Windows. My answer advocates leaving OSX for its own merits. There are many rescue CDs or USBs for both systems if the worse happens, but there is no need for increasing the chances for needing such rescue. I have answered a question here about MacBook where a Windows function only worked correctly after first booting OSX (drivers problem), and no other solution was ever found. So I still believe in letting OSX stay, just in case.