# Can I format the Macintosh HD from Windows with Bootcamp?

Tags: windows-7, macos, formatting, boot-camp, macbook-air

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove Mac OS X and install Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/73965/remove-mac-os-x-and-install-windows)

I got a Macbook Air from work, but I only need Windows programs. I use Bootcamp to create a Windows partition and installed W7 on it. I never boot to Mac OS, but the Mac partition uses up 16GB that I would love to use from Windows but can't.

So here is my question: Can I format the Mac partition to NTFS or FAT32 from W7? I understand that Mac OS will be gone completely, but as I said, I never use it, so I don't mind. I am just concerned that the laptop will not boot to Windows any more for whatever reason (e.g. deleting boot files).

Thanks for the help!

BJ

Comment: The apple website has documentation that explains how to do this.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, I can't find anything using the search. Everything I found was about formatting the windows partition, which is not what I want to do.

Comment: Not really. My question is if I can safely format the Mac partition, not if I can install W7 only without OS X.

Comment: Ok, I tried it myself. Luckily, it worked.

I did not format the partition in Windows, but went to the Recovery partition, used DiskUtility and formated the Mac partition to FAT (loosing 650MB, apparently). Then I booted W7 (it worked!) and formated the partition to NTFS. No problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

The OP was able to answer this question:

> I did not format the partition in Windows, but went to the Recovery partition, used DiskUtility and formated the Mac partition to FAT (loosing 650MB, apparently). Then I booted W7 (it worked!) and formated the partition to NTFS. No problems so far.