# Can I load Windows 7 as the native OS on a macbook laptop without using bootcamp?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, macbook

I've recently had a macbook laptop fall into my possession. It belonged to a friend of mine, but she doesn't want it any more because it doesn't work. From what I understand, the hard drive stopped working in it; more particularly it emitted the distinctive hard drive "death rattle" sound and then the computer stopped being able to boot to mac OS X.

I have the laptop here with a dead hard drive in it. Would it be possible to go on newegg.com or somewhere of the sort and order a new laptop hard drive, say, a Western Digital Scorpio:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136197

and install it in the laptop? And even if I did that, I don't have a mac OS X installation CD. Could I just load Windows 7 on it instead?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, but it's not going to be exactly like installing on a PC.

Related question with more information [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/64842/installing-windows-7-64-bit-on-a-mac-pro-without-bootcamp)

Some very important considerations there you should read before proceeding!