# Install Windows on Mac Natively

Tags: windows-7, mac

I'm interested in buying the new 2011 Mac Mini. I want it because of the hardware. I can't seems to find a comparable PC that is as fast, small and quiet. I don't care for Mac OS X at all.

Is it possible to install Windows 7 Ultimate on the mac on a fresh empty hdd from a usb drive?

Can the mac boot from an external USB HDD that has Windows already installed on it?

Comment: I've been googling and so far I can't find instruction to install windows without boot camp. As far as I know mac doesn't have BIOS like the one on pc.

Comment: Doh!  Macs use EFI, but don't implement the right bits that Windows 7 requires for booting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Windows 7 (64 bit) on a Mac Pro without Boot Camp?](http://superuser.com/questions/64842/installing-windows-7-64-bit-on-a-mac-pro-without-boot-camp)

Comment: yeah but it doesn't really answer my question. The vista instruction require cd/dvd to install windows, how about usb drives? since the mini doesn't have cd/dvd drives and I don't want to buy external drives just to install windows.

Comment: Why? I seriously can't think of any reason why you'd rather use windows!

Comment: What makes the USB drive significantly different than an optical?  You're talking about the same boot code in either case.  [This answer](http://superuser.com/questions/64842/installing-windows-7-64-bit-on-a-mac-pro-without-boot-camp/218177#218177) indicates that Windows 7 may "just boot" on a new Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a new boot loader in that case. And it looks like you'll need to convert the drive to GPT unless you install a custom bootloader like GRUB.

- [How to install Windows 7 EFI from bootable USB flash drive](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproinstall/thread/d1f1dc9d-4384-40a3-9434-a4437b0ff796)
- [Installing Windows 7 in native EFI mode from USB - bit-tech.net Forums](http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=209045)
- [Installing Windows to an EFI-Based Computer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744321(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: the instruction require disc

Comment: can anybody confirm this will work on mac, since as far as i know mac efi implementation is a bit different

Comment: You only have to boot it past the boot manager. In a sense, your current bootloader won't boot up in EFI.  But the Windows 7 efi bootloader won't boot Mac OSX.  So you'll need to either A) get a custom bootloader or B) replace the Windows 7 bootloader with the EFI version and then add an entry to the Mac OS X bootloader to point to that bootloader.

Comment: I think there is misunderstanding here, the hdd will be fresh empty. Is the mac bios/efi able to boot my windows 7 installation usb flash drives ?

Comment: You posted that the External already has Win 7 installed. Yes, the OSX is capable of booting the Win7 boot loader.