# Is there a way to install Windows 7 on MacMini without Bootcamp?

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot-camp

I want to install Windows 7 on the MacMini (2007 era, 2GB, Core2Duo, 80 GB HDD).  I'd like to do so without BootCamp.  In other words, I'd like to completely get rid of Mac OS from the hard drive.

There is already a similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/319268/install-windows-on-mac-natively), but it deals with booting Windows directly from an external drive.  I'd like to take it to the next level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Install windows 7 without bootcamp: Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3613819?start=0&tstart=0):

> - Step 1: take out primary os x lion hdd out and put your secondary hdd in there
> - Step 2 put the super drive in its place
> - Step 3 install os x lion in an external drive (don't use your primary drive) you only need recovery HD
> - Step 4 run recovery HD from external drive
> - Step 5 press the apple logo and restart system
> - Step 6 boot up pressing the option key
> - Step 7 there should be a windows cd and a EFI cd
> - Step 8 click the windows cd
> - Step 9 install windows 7
> - Step 10 install the apple drivers
> - Step 11 put the clean windows 7 drive in the optical bay
> - Step 12 put the primary drive in the primary sata slot

Comment: It sounds like this would work, but I have a MacMini.  Removing hard drives is literally heart surgery.