# Install / uninstall GPU drivers in Win7 via file explorer?

Tags: windows-7, installation, drivers, file-management, gpu

### Situation:

- (*[See also for context: a previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/769620/macbook-pro-disable-win7-discrete-gpu-with-no-screen-access)*)
- Cannot access Win7 (bootcamp) system via screen, as AMD GPU is bust
- Win7 Safe Mode does not help
- Can run OSX partition as managed to manually disable AMD drivers via single-user boot

So...

### What I want to do:

What I want to try to do is disable the Win7 AMD (Radeon HD 6490M) driver via Mac's Finder.app (have NTFS rw capability).

How would I go about that? Is it possible?

---

**Follow-up question**

Can I then manually install a *Intel HD Graphics 3000* driver purely via Finder?

Comment: If you attempt this its very likely you will cause Windows to become unbootable.  What was wrong with your previous question?

Comment: FYI, safe mode _does_ start Windows using a basic VGA driver and not the AMD driver.

Comment: @Jason I'll have to retry Safe Mode tomorrow then... can't imagine why it didn't work before.

Answer (score 1):

Device configuration is stored in the registry file `C:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM`.  However, I'm not aware of OS X having any way of editing a Windows registry file.

If you want to edit the registry without using Windows, you could use something like [Offline NT](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/).  You will find keys related to display driver configuration under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video`.

Comment: Not really. The `NTUSER.DAT` file is mapped to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` registry hive. Device configuration is stored in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` branch under the `SYSTEM` subkey. The actual data is stored in an identically named file which is located in the `Windows\System32\config` folder.

Comment: @and31415 Yes, of course, my bad.  I've corrected my answer and elaborated even further.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the AMD drivers (`atikmdag.sys` and `atikmpag.sys`) in `Windows\System32\Drivers`. Now Windows should not start the AMD GPU.